# What is the use case difference/benefit of using a Gray code vs. Incremental rotary encoder

Tags: encoder, rotary

I am planning to build a small digital project where a rotary encoder would be ideal for sending "up/down signals" (e.g. scrolling through a list on screen).

Are there any benefits of using a Gray code vs. an Incremental rotary encoder for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences between Grey coding and incremental coding, on a per-code basis, are nil.  Incremental coding is basically 2-bit Gray coding which has been compressed and repeated into a series of "clicks". There is no difference between one rotation of Gray coding and one click of incremental coding.

The main difference is that Gray coding covers the full 360° with the code sequence, whereas incremental covers just one little portion of it, and that sequence is repeated.

Gray coding is perfect when you are interested in full rotations, and need to know where in the rotation you are at any one point in time. It is usually used as a rotational indication on motor shafts for accurate positioning.

Incremental coding is only really interested in which direction the shaft has moved and how far, not exactly where it is.  Most encoders used as control knobs are of the incremental type, since you don't care where it is, only that it turned clockwise 4 clicks.

Comment: I thought the advantage of gray code was that only one bit changed at a time, so you never had the case of a false reading (as two bits change at once, but not quite at the same time.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I thought that too, but then I found that incremental is basically 2-bit gray that's compressed into small incremental "clicks". INcremental coding != binary coding.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Incremental coding is 2-bit Gray coding compressed into small clicks, so a change in either system yields the same (or similar) results - one changed bit.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle, Ahh got it thanks, Incremental is like a quadrature output, it just tells you which way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder#Incremental_rotary_encoder

Comment: @GeorgeHerold  Quadrature encoders are one form of incremental encoder.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle  Incremental encoding can be quadrature, which would make your sentence accurate but it doesn't have to be.  It can be tick and direction.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I have re-worded it since no one understood what I was getting at with that sentence.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle  Thx -- deleted my comment

Answer (score 5):

A Gray code encoder is an ABSOLUTE encoder.  You turn your system on, do a reading, and you know the position of what you're trying to measure to within the resolution of the encoder.  For these encoders, you often need a digital I/O for every bit of resolution of the encoder.

In contrast, an incremental encoder is a RELATIVE encoder.  You turn the system on, it starts at zero, or some other predetermined number, and accurately reports RELATIVE position from the starting position.  If you want to know absolute position, you need to go through some sort of zeroing process, often involving slow motion to some sort of fixed location switch.  For these encoders, you only need one or two bits of I/O (usually) to handle the data.

As for Gray code vs binary code (another option for absolute encoder that you didn't ask about), in a Gray code only one bit at a time changes, making handling of the signals more bulletproof.